# How do I make a call to PHP api to check for new notifications in Ionic and display notification?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have developed an app in ionic. It works as needed but I want to check for new events every 30 minutes. I have PHP code ready for that, but how do I schedule notification and show notification if new events are available.
Currently the app will be deployed only on android.

Answer (score 0):

## copied

The plugin supports **scheduling** local **notifications** in various ways with a single interface. It also allows you to update, clear or cancel them. There are different interfaces to query for local **notifications** and a complete set of events to hook into the life cycle of local **notifications**.[Sample code on github](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)

Comment: I am unable to use any cordova.any_plugin.function() in ionic